# How to save many images through a script php

Tags: php, android

In my app android, I take photos with android camera and I send these photos to pc through this script PHP :

```
<?php
 $base=$_REQUEST['image'];
 $binary=base64_decode($base);
 header('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8');
 $file = fopen('uploaded_image.jpg', 'wb');
 fwrite($file, $binary);
 fclose($file);
 echo 'Image upload complete!!, Please check your php file directory……';
```

?>

I obtain the photo correctly to my pc, but when I send an other photo, this overwrite the previous photo..because the name ("uploaded_image.jpg") is the same.
It's possibile to assign different names so I can save all the photos ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [**uniqid**](https://www.php.net/uniqid) to create a unique file name each time,

```
$fileName = uniqid().'.jpg';
$file = fopen($fileName , 'wb');
```

Comment: ok and the what's this name ? because I have an other script which save the foto to db with this instruction : $inviofoto = mysqli_query($con, "insert into Foto (immagine) values ((LOAD_FILE('C:/Desktop/uploaded_image.jpg'))");

Comment: See my update. You can use `$filenNme` for db insertion.

Comment: ok but the query to save the photo is in an other script..how I obtain the variable $fileName ?

Comment: Why not to save image on the same page & just use `$fileName` ?

Comment: ok and how can I write correctly my query ? $inviofoto = mysqli_query($con, "insert into Foto (immagine) values ((LOAD_FILE('C:/Desktop/$fileName'))");  it's correct ?

Comment: Could not run query: Column 'Immagine' cannot be null

Answer (score 0):

you can use PHP time() function. It will add timestamp with photo name.

```
$file = fopen(time().'uploaded_image.jpg', 'wb');


<?php
 $base=$_REQUEST['image'];
 $binary=base64_decode($base);
 header('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8');
 $file = fopen(time().'uploaded_image.jpg', 'wb');
 fwrite($file, $binary);
 fclose($file);
 echo 'Image upload complete!!, Please check your php file directory……';
  ?>
```